# CakePHP share Login function for REST and Form authentication?

Tags: rest, cakephp, authentication

So my **CakePHP** is a website which happens to have a mobile app. In the website, I'm using **form-based authentication**. Now I'm trying to do **REST** authentication. I decided that my **REST** calls are going to be **Basic Authentication**.

Since all my **REST** calls are going to be authenticated, should I create a different login function such as `UsersController::api_login()` for **REST** or should I share the same `UsersController::login()` function I use to authenticate the website?

Answer (score 0):

I did it using this method, if the request that is coming into the application is a .json (or anything else for that matter), switch to Basic auth:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    // Change the authentication if using REST
    if($this->params['ext'] == 'json') {
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic');
    }

}
```

Comment: And it automatically attempts to log in using credentials in Header instead of Form, right?.  Now, that should work for requests like `/students/index.json`, but what url should I use for **just a login request**?

Comment: Is this just so you can fetch the details of the authenticated user?

Comment: more like to confirm de credentials are correct, in order to save them as preference

Comment: I would create a function in the users controller called user_details or something like that, which would perform that function.